# PHP não consegue processar arquivos pesados

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, txt

Tenho um sistema em PHP que lê um arquivo TXT, e realiza um REPLACE no banco de dados para cada linha, ele faz isso bem com arquivos pequeno (Cerca de 100 linhas), todavia quando faço com arquivos gigantes (Mais de 1 Milhão de linhas) o Chrome fica com uma tela branca e não funciona. Como faço pra rodar algo grande assim no navegador?

Esse é um exemplo de linha:

```
2018-09-03;AALR3                                             ;0000000090; 000000000012.690000;000000000000000400;10:01:00.021;1;2018-09-03;000086402559117;000000000200197;2;2018-09-03;000086402555935;000000000200198;2;0;00000003;00000003
```

Uso só as 7 primeiras informações, então uso este código abaixo:

```
<?php

$conexao = mysqli_connect("generic_ip", "genericlogin", "generickey", "genericdatabase");

if ($_POST) {
    $count=0;
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
    $ler = file($tmp_name);
    $total = count($ler);
    $controler = 0;

    foreach ($ler as $linhas) {
if($controler > 0){
        $base = $linhas;
        $corrigibase = (explode(";", $base));
        $dado0 = trim($corrigibase[0]);
        $dado1 = trim($corrigibase[1]);


        $dado2 = trim($corrigibase[2]);
        $dado2 = floatval($dado2);
        $dado3 = trim($corrigibase[3]);
        $dado3 = floatval($dado3);
        $dado4 = trim($corrigibase[4]);
        $dado4 = floatval($dado4);


        $dado5 = trim($corrigibase[5]);
        $dado6 = trim($corrigibase[6]);

        $QUERY_MORE = "REPLACE INTO genericdatabase.generictable (Data, Papel, N_neg, Preco, Quant_Neg, Hora, Ind_anul) VALUES ('$dado0', '$dado1', '$dado2', '$dado3', '$dado4', '$dado5', '$dado6')";

        $INSERT_BASE = mysqli_query($conexao, $QUERY_MORE);

$count++;
        $dado0 = NULL;
        $dado1 = NULL;
        $dado2 = NULL;
        $dado3 = NULL;
        $dado4 = NULL;
        $dado5 = NULL;
        $dado6 = NULL;
}
$controler++;

    }

    echo $count."registros contados";

}

?>
```

Comment: A tela fica banca devido a demora pro servidor conseguir executar todas as linhas...O tempo depende de acordo com a capacidade de processamento da maquina. Mas algum erro acontece?

Comment: A função [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) vai ler o arquivo inteiro e bota pra mémoria de uma vez, então uma coisa que pode estar acontecendo é tu não ter memória suficiente pra ler isso, por padrão o php vem com limite de 250mb. Se for realmente isso tu pode usa [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13246630/9643815) tem um exemplo de como usar a função pra processar linha por linha.

Comment: @edsonalves, nenhum outro erro acontece, somente esse

Comment: @fajuchem, o tamanho do arquivo dá cerca de 270 mb, então faz sentido o que você diz, não botei na pergunta, mas esse arquivo é importado pelo usuario, como usaria o fopen neste caso?

Comment: @GeraldãodeRívia Alguem já deu exemplo de como utilizar o fopen nas respostas, além disso eu botei um link do comentário acima. Vale lembrar também que é possível aumentar o limite de memória do php pra ter certeza que esse é realmente o problema. Se tiver usando xampp [aqui](https://cursos7.com.br/como-aumentar-o-limite-de-memoria-do-xampp/) mostra como aumentar a memória.

Comment: @fajuchem, tentei com a forma q foi recomendada acima abaixo e msm assim não funcionou, funcionou com arquivos menores, mas com arquivo grande dá o mesmo problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É, com 1 milhão de linhas já  é necessário fazer as operações por stream linha a linha, a principal modificação seria as seguintes linhas:

```
//abrir com fopen ou invés do file()
$ler = fopen($tmp_name, 'r');

//usar o while com fgets ao invés do foreach do seu código pra percorrer
//cada linha separadamente, não carregando todo o arquivo em memória
while ($linha = fgets($ler)) { ... }

//fecha o arquivo depois do while
fclose($ler);
```

Comment: Msm assim não funcionou, funcionou com arquivos pequenos, mas com arquivos grandes tá a mesma coisa ainda

Comment: acredito que a quantidade de operações SQL também seja o problema, tente fazer menos operações concatenando mais values na string SQL,  [veja exemplo aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452934/3912299), tipo leia 250 linhas e concateneas com sintaxe correta, quando terminar essas 250 manda executar o sql e prossiga pras proximas 250 linhas, assim vc faz apenas 4 mil queries ao inves de 1 milhao, se tiver muitas duvidas faz outra pergunta sobre isso

Comment: Mas mesmo assim, não devia subir alguma coisa na base antes de travar?